# angular unit testing service with dependencies exported as ES6 module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, module, ecmascript-6

my setup is fairly unique in that I haven't been able to find good examples of how to do this. I have a es6 module that is exporting an angular service. I want to test this service. It has two dependencies, of which will also have dependencies.

I don't really care about that as I don't need to call any functions on them, I just need to get my tests to run.

main file

```
import angular from '/angularjs'

export default angular.module('utils', [])
.service('utils', ['modal', 'printModal', function (modal, printModal) {

  this.doubleValue = function(value) {
    return value * 2
  }
}])
```

test file

```
import angular from '/angularjs'
import utils from 'app/workbooks/utilsHmm' // this is where the other file is

let utilsService
describe('utils', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('utils')

    var $injector = angular.injector([ 'utils' ]);
    utilsService = $injector.get( 'utils' );
  })

  it('should double the value', () => {
      expect(utilsService.doubleValue(2)).toEqual(4)
  })
})
```

utilsService seems to be working, but the test runner complains about the dependencies.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: modalProvider <- modal <- utils

I really just want to replace the dependencies with two empty objects. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use `angular.injector`. You're trying to reinvent the features of ngMock with this.

Comment: estus - could you give me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing Usually you load modules and define mocks with `angular.mock.module` (or `module`) and create injector with `angular.mock.inject` (or `inject`).

Comment: if I take out the injector, the utils service now equals this object Object{_invokeQueue: [[..., ..., ...]], _configBlocks: [], _runBlocks: [], requires: [], name: 'utils', provider: function (recipeName, factoryFunction) { ... }, factory: function (recipeName, factoryFunction) { ... }, service: function (recipeName, factoryFunction) { ... }, value: function () { ... }, constant: function () { ... }, decorator: function (recipeName, factor... this isn't my service

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done to get this but it is module object (if you've got it with `angular.module('utils')`, then you should know that it isn't the same thing as `angular.mock.module('utils')`). Just follow the way to use `module` and `inject` (angular.mock.module and and angular.mock.inject in your case) that is suggested in the manual, [it is very specific on how Angular specs should be written](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller).